# Efficiently accessing arbitrary NDArray batches in mxnet

Tags: python, python-2.7, mxnet

Fitting convnets such as Resnet and VGG benefits from the ImageRecordIter python class, that allows efficiently loading batches from large collections of RGB images stored in RecordIO .rec files,

Does anybody know about equivalent facilities for large arbitrary input 2D or 3D matrices (for 2D, rows = items and cols = features, + channels in 3D)?

NDArrayIter requires loading the whole dataset in memory, which is to be avoided in my case (>40Gb data file). CSVIter does not allow straightforward shuffling, and works only for 2D matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep each data sample as a separate file and implement a very simple custom `DataSet` class following the reference code [ImageFolderDataset](https://mxnet.apache.org/_modules/mxnet/gluon/data/vision/datasets.html#ImageFolderDataset)